# Maintaining multiple copies of the same file in different repos under different revision control systems

Tags: git, svn

**Situation**

I have developed a wordpress plugin. It's a jQuery slider. 
So, it includes code for slider (in jQuery), let's say in `slider.js` and also the wordpress php files for admin panel.

Now, I have to maintain 3 different project folders.

1. Folder/directory involving jQuery file + php files for wordpress plugin repository. WP uses `svn`, and a specific folder structure to host plugins there.
2. Folder for github main project ( includes jQuery + php files)
3. Folder for github pages for `gh-pages` branch. This folder contains only jQuery files (not the php files used for wordpress) as I am only showing demo of my slider on `gh-pages`

**Problem**

Whenever I update my `slider.js` file, I need to manually update it in all three folders and push all the three repositories separately.

I need some easy solution to automate the problem.

**ps:**

*feel free to suggest edits in question or title.*

Comment: How about: _Maintaining an identical file under different paths in multiple repos under different revision control systems_?

Comment: Perhaps take a note of the commands you use to update the file once, then write a script to do those things for you?

Comment: @gcbenison, I didnt get you. Can you rephrase ?

Comment: @jashwant I meant, how about that as the title for the question?

Comment: @twalberg, that's something but still I need to maintain 3 copies and learn some linux (shell) programming. Right ?

Comment: @Jashwant In the short term, yes. I think the better overall solution is to learn to use the `git-svn` interface to `svn`, and `git submodule` and `git branch`.

Comment: @twalberg, can you add an answer giving a much more detail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best answer for this is to learn how to use `git-svn` to create a `git` "clone" of the `svn` repository, that is able to correctly interact with the original repository for fetching new changesets and contributing new ones. This is a somewhat different workflow than just plain `git`, though, so there's a learning curve.

In addition, learning to use `git submodule` correctly, and fully separating the `jQuery` bits into one repository, and the `php` bits into a separate repository that is a submodule of the main repository (or some other arrangement of main repository with submodules - I'm not entirely sure which makes more sense to have has the main) would help. Again, though, there's a learning curve involved, so it may take some time. Proper use of branches in the various repositories is also critical.

For the short term, figuring out the list of commands needed to be run after one copy of the file is updated, and using them to write a script to propagate the changes into the other repositories will reduce the manual workload and help avoid mistakes.